# How to efficiently estimate merchentable volume for timber inventory using species, DBH, and merchentable heights?

Tags: measurements, agriculture, data-analysis, forest

I am trying to estimate wood volume for forest stands I have field-inventoried using a variable plot sample method, measuring species, DBH, and height of each tree counted 'in' using a BAF-10 prism. In my area, International-1/4 log rule is used to estimate volumes. I found [a table for that](http://www.uky.edu/%7Ejmlhot2/bdft_tables/table_5.htm) in general but not specific to species. In any case, it also seems very tedious to lookup each volume based on DBH & height I recorded, since there are about 220 measures trees over 21 plots for a ~50 acre forest.

How do professionals efficiently apply DBH and height to estimate volumes? I imagine there is a digital lookup table of volumes, ideally per species, and there is a way to programmatically (in a spreadsheet) lookup the volume based on row corresponding with DBH and column corresponding with height. I have not been able to find digital lookup tables for species however (only PDF or paper ones), or a method for that kind of row-col lookup in Excel.

I am in NY, USA, with majority species being eastern hemlock, red maple, yellow birch, black cherry, red spruce, and balsam fir.